# facebook/twitter post share in Unity

Tags: facebook, twitter, unity-game-engine, share

I want to integrate social sharing in Unity for iOS and Android, any help would be appreciated except paid plugins link.

Answer (score 1):

- Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/
- Twitter: because Twitter doesn't have official SDK, so that I use:

  > For iOS: twitter.framework
  >
  > For Android: https://github.com/3pillarlabs/socialauth-android